# Restart Windows Service on a remote server from an web application using Service Controller?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I have some windows services in machine1 and a web application running on Machine2. I need to restart services on machine1 through C# code in my web application process. What is the best way of achieving this?

Comment: Did you experience any problems with the obvious, simple way?

Comment: Running a web application with the privileges required to interact with a remote service seems like a bad idea

Comment: @nvoigt the requirement is to have a interface in web application for restarting those services. Not sure about the obvious way you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

You can add another service to machine 1 which when invoked, can restart the a service on the same machine. Then call it from your web application. More info can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

@Mahdi has provided a good approach I will also suggest you same.

Create another Windows Service which will continuously run on machine 2 and checks if the required `Service` status is `Stopped` if found it will restart that `Service` immediately.

you can use `ServiceController` to restart the service like this:

```
ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName);
TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds); //Time out to make sure if service has started correctly
service.Start();
service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timeout);
```